# Apache 2.2.3 and Tomcat 6.0 : JSESSIONID being duplicated on different Sessions

Tags: apache, tomcat6, session-cookies, mod-proxy, jsessionid

We are running the following:

- On Linux OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 - 64 bit
- Apache Tomcat/6.0.20 - Serving Java EE Website
- Apache/2.2.3 64 bit - Sitting in front of Tomcat
- Running mod_proxy on Apache to server Tomcat website**

Randomly occurring problem. Normally, this does NOT happen. **When visitors view website (even on different networks) they will get SAME JSESSIONID.** Example:

**64AAD378FCACF2D2526AA40EAB277073** - ROB (On network #1)
**64AAD378FCACF2D2526AA40EAB277073** - NICK (On network #1)
**64AAD378FCACF2D2526AA40EAB277073** - LAURA (On network #1)
**64AAD378FCACF2D2526AA40EAB277073** - TIM  (On network #2)

From my understanding, JSESSIONID is UNIQUE identify so visitors session can be tracked server side. Each NEW browser session should have different JSESSIONID and session. Otherwise you will get the problem we are having where OTHER user's logged in account information is displayed. It is like the LINES are crossed and people are crossing over into other people's account.

This is Production issue. The only most recent change has been putting Apache in front of Tomcat. Is that somehow "caching" the Java session and giving it out to multiple people?

If users closes their browser, logs out of current session, or cleans their cookies... they get a new unique JSESSIONID and new session.

Have searched FAR and wide, but can't find if anyone is having same problem or fixes.

**PLEASE HELP!**

Comment: There are so many ways this could be happening. It could be a configuration issue, it could be an application issue, it could be caused by some other component. There isn't enough information in the question for anyone to be able to provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. We ended up restarting the server and visitors were getting new/different JSESSIONIDs. I wrote some code that will ping our website every 15 minutes and check for duplicate JSESSIONIDs and alert us if it happens again.

What additional information, config files, etc do you feel could help someone diagnose this problem? Any suggestions on tools or ways to diagnose problem?